# html loads html continuously by ajax load() (no JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my concept is to load html file from one to another one. The image below could explain better.For example, I have `no1.html, no2.html,no3.html, no4.html ...` and they share one JavaScript file, all html files have its own contents.

first HTML file no1.html loads no2.html,  my javascript is for no1.html like, `$('#element').load('no2.html #content');` then no2.html js is like `$('#element').load('no3.html #content');`

if all files just share one javascript file is unable to load html pages continuously, is there a way to make html loads another html continuously ?

[image]

Comment: If you want to make a presentation look at [Reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/)

Comment: Do you want to replace no1.html to no2.html or nest no2 into no1 ?

Comment: @naota I wanted to nest no2 into no1, and no3 into no2

Comment: @olo, would you like to load a next html automatically in some time period, or load on click event?

Comment: @naota, yes, to load on click event. so like, open no1 then no1 loads no2 automatically, then click no2.html's link to load no3, continuously. sounds complected  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

**my.js**

```
$(function() {

      // delegate click event to ajax content
      $("body").on("click",".load_button",function() { 

        $(this).hide(); // hide this button
        var area_name = $(this).data("area");
        var next_file = $(this).data("next");
        $("#"+area_name).load(next_file);
    });
});
```

**no1.html**

```
<script src="my.js"></script>

This is No.1
.....
<div id="area_2">no2 will be here</div>
<div class="load_button" data-area="area_2" data-next="no2.html">Click</div>
```

**no2.html**

```
This is No.2
.....
<div id="area_3">no3 will be here</div>
<div class="load_button" data-area="area_3" data-next="no3.html">Click</div>
```

**no3.html**

```
This is No.3
.....
<div id="area_4">no4 will be here</div>
<div class="load_button" data-area="area_4" data-next="no4.html">Click</div>
```

In this example, `my.js` is included only once in `no1.html`.  
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. no1, no2, no3 wanted them to have same html structure

Answer (score 0):

1.You are trying to load the content of the html file in single element.
You might want to use a callback function

```
$('#element').load('no3.html #content' ,function(){
// Loading done.. what next?
})
```

Comment: if load one by one like ? `$('#element').load('no3.html #content' ,function(){
   $('#element').load('no4.html #content');
})`